# SQL: changing parameter driving output depending on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to determine the best approach.  In this we have many entities and claims for members of these entities.  The claims inherently don't have the idea of the entity, which I'll have a subquery that bring together membership and claims.  My question is that each entity has specific sources of claims that are to be included.

and claimource in (when entity 1 then source a & b, when entity 2 then source a, when entity 3 then source a, b, c)

```
and c.PD_PRD_YYYYMM between '201401' and (select to_char(sysdate - 45,   'YYYYMM') from dual) -- analyst adjust 
and c.CLM_SRC_CD in (when c.entity = 'Entity 1' then 'Source A', when c.entity = 'Entity 2' then 'Source A & Source B', etc...)
```

I'm stuck on the c.CLM_SRC_CD part as I don't know if you need a case statement. This conceptually is going to be used in multiple spots. I made great progress at some point, but it's buried in my thousands of crashed editors

I'm not sure if a case statement is appropriate here?  Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Which flavor of SQL are you using (Sql-Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc)? Second, you need to show a sample schema with some data, desired output and anything you have tried.  As it stands, it isn't very clear what you need (which will dictate how to solve this).

Comment: It's an Oracle Instance.

Comment: and c.PD_PRD_YYYYMM between '201401' and (select to_char(sysdate - 45, 'YYYYMM') from dual) -- analyst adjust
    and c.CLM_SRC_CD in (when c.entity = 'Entity 1' then 'Source A', when c.entity = 'Entity 2' then 'Source A & Source B', etc...)  I'm stuck on the c.CLM_SRC_CD part as I don't know if you need a case statement.  This conceptually is going to be used in multiple spots.  I made great progress at some point, but it's buried in my thousands of crashed editors.

Comment: Looks like something got cut off in copy and paste.  Also, edit that information into the question, don't just leave it in a comment.

Comment: I can't provide any data, I could probably produce some dummy data.  The whole query is a lot to digest and I'm just trying to keep it simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

While I am no expert in Oracle SQL, this or something close should do it:

```
where...
and ((c.Entity = 'Thing 1' and c.CLM_SRC_CD in (select ... from SourceA))
     or (c.Entity = 'Thing 2' and c.CLM_SRC_CD in (select ... from SourceB)))
```

Using `and`s and `or`s allows it to work kind of like a case statement but allows you to specify the subqueries to us in an `in` check.